# PHP echo data from different table

Tags: php, echo

My system has 2 different accounts staff and student.

Both users account details(login, names) are stored in the useraccount table. 
Student has another table called Task.

I logged in as a staff and I want to view a student's tasks by clicking on the view link next to their name.

Right now if I click on a student's view link it will just bring up everything in the task table, but that is not what I want it should only display whatever is belongs to this student. I am not sure how to do this could you please help?

```
 <?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>  
<td><?php echo $row['username'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['firstname'] ; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['surname'] ; ?></td>
<td><a href="viewStudent.php<?php echo'?task_id='.$row['task.account_id']; ?>">
View Account</a></td>
<?php
} 
}
?>
```

Here is the database table:

```
CREATE TABLE userAccount (
account_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(7) NOT NULL,
password varchar(8) NOT NULL,
firstname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
surname varchar (30) NOT NULL,
email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
permission ENUM('Student', 'Staff') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (account_id)
)


CREATE TABLE staff (
staff_id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
account_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (staff_id),
FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES userAccount(account_id)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `task` (
`task_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`taskName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 `starts` date NOT NULL,
`finish` date NOT NULL,
`progress` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`account_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`staff_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
 KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
 KEY `staff_id` (`staff_id`)
 )
```

Comment: Without the actual query that the `mysqli_fetch_array()` is based on, it's pretty much impossible to guess at how to update your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the code for viewStudent.php or the query used for the while loop so I'm limited in how I can help.

However, I would assume this sql query will work for viewStudent.php.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE account_id=".intval($_GET['task_id']);
```

Comment: <?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['account_id']))
   {
   $account_id = $_SESSION['account_id'];
   $query = "SELECT staff.staff_id, staff.account_id,        task.task_id,task.staff_id, useraccount.username,    useraccount.firstname, useraccount.surname, useraccount.account_id    FROM useraccount,staff, task WHERE    task.account_id=useraccount.account_id AND    task.staff_id=staff.staff_id AND staff.account_id=$account_id"; 
  $result= mysqli_query($con,$query);

Answer (score -1):

You did not give your main query above but I think you are missing account_id = $account_id condition.

@user3341382 It seems you are sending parameter with `task_id` name and trying to use as `account_id` in your session. (comment based on your query given in comments for James T's answer)

Comment: Thanks for downvote and sharing your query in comment above. It is not possible to answer this question with given code